# How to force SharePoint tasks to be editable by “Assigned To” only?

Tags: workflow, task-list

I am creating task using visual studio workflow 2013, when user uploaded document we starting workflow which create task for group. But current logged in user is not member of that group. Then also he can able to approve the task. As he is creator of task item.

Please suggest me how I can handle this condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to create an event handler that updates the permission on the Task everytime the assigned user is changed.

You can check the following to add permissions to your workflow tasks:

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/66248-restrict-a-sharepoint-task-to-its-assigned-user-group

https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/workflow-tasks-viewable-most-not-task-92134.aspx

Comment: Second link is not opening, And I am using visual studio workflow 2013 so how we can use "Impersonation Step" in it.

Comment: Second link is working fine. What kind of impersonation you want to use?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Workflow 2013, So I didn't know how to use impersonation in it.

Comment: You can avoid that step, create the workflow and test.

Comment: But it required for me,As that what I want to achieve

Comment: So in visual studio workflow you can create your custom action and write your custom code there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231574(v=vs.100).aspx